# Reuse SqlPlus session when supplying queries via the PowerShell pipeline

Tags: oracle, powershell, sqlplus

This function will execute multiple queries that are supplied via the pipeline:

```
function Invoke-SqlPlus
{
    param(
        [Parameter(Position=0,Mandatory=$true,ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        [string[]]$Query
    )

    Begin {
        $SID=Read-Host 'SID'
        $user=Read-Host 'User'
        $password=Read-Host 'Password'

        # authenticate once here?

    }
    Process {
        foreach ($Q In $Query) {
            Write-Verbose $Q

            # append ';' if necessary
            if ( $Q.substring($Q.length-1) -Ne ';' ) { $Q += ';' }

            # execute query
            $Q | sqlplus -S "$user/$password@$SID"
        }
    }
    End {
        # formally end session here?
    }
}

"SELECT sysdate FROM dual","SELECT * FROM all_tables" | Invoke-SqlPlus
```

Unfortunately, the performance suffers a bit from repeated logons.  Is there a way to reuse the sqlplus session?

** edit **

Goals:

- Return the result as an object, rather than a string (the current state creates a string that must be parsed).
- Process queries on the pipeline, rather than having to save them in a file.

Comment: Do you have an ODBC driver for Oracle that you can use instead of `sqlplus.exe`?

Comment: I decided on this approach, as I'm experimenting with PowerShell on OS X.  Not sure if there's an ODBC implementation for OS X.

Comment: why not $sqlplus -S u/p@tns <<EOF line1:queryA line2:queryB EOF ? or generate a file with the list of queries and fire off in sqlplus -S u/p@tns @file